# What is the minimal number of blocks of a SecureFile LOB?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Does anybody know how SecureFile stores LOBs into chunks? The documentation says the `CHUNK` parameter is only advisory (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e18294/adlob_smart.htm#CIHIDGJA).

I did some initial tests, it looks like Oracle uses minimally one block per LOB (EDIT: if it is stored in the lobsegment). Is that right?

```
CREATE TABLE sftest (mylob CLOB) 
  LOB (mylob) STORE AS SECUREFILE sftest_mylob (DISABLE STORAGE IN ROW);

INSERT INTO sftest SELECT object_name FROM all_objects;
11,825 rows inserted

SELECT blocks FROM user_segments WHERE segment_name='SFTEST_MYLOB';
14336
```

Comment: Minimally one chunk per LOB not stored in the row. Chunk size is one or more database blocks. This would only make a difference if you made the database block size small and chunk size ended up more than one database block. Then LOBs would minimally take more than one database block.

Comment: @Brian That sounds exactly like `BASICFILE`, so the storage is the same?

Comment: Except there is no documentation that SECUREFILE always uses one database block - just that it ignores chunk size and does it's own thing. Can try using a database with a block size of 2k and see if uses one or more blocks per LOB not stored in row minimum.

Comment: @Brian So, what's it's own thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the minimal number of blocks of a SecureFile LOB is 1 (if it is not stored in row).

We are using SecureFile LOBs for a number of years in production, and I found out how to inspect the block number of an individual LOB. First, you need to get the number of extents the LOB has by calling `DBMS_LOBUTIL.GETINODE(mylob).EXTENTS`, then you can find out for each extent, how many blocks are stored it it with `DBMS_LOBUTIL.GETLOBMAP(mylob, myextent).NBLKS`, e.g.

```
SELECT DBMS_LOBUTIL.GETINODE(mylob).LENGTH    AS len,
       DBMS_LOBUTIL.GETINODE(mylob).EXTENTS   AS extents,
       DBMS_LOBUTIL.GETLOBMAP(mylob, 0).NBLKS AS nblks           
  FROM sftest;

LEN  EXTENTS NBLKS
 34        1     1
 24        1     1
 42        1     1
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, minimum one block per LOB is incorrect.  It can be much smaller, depending on the size of your LOB.  From the [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28393/adlob_tables.htm)

> LOB values are stored inline when any of the following conditions
>   apply:
>
> When the size of the LOB stored in the given row is small, approximately 4000 bytes or less, and you either explicitly specify
>   ENABLE STORAGE IN ROW or the LOB storage clause when you create the
>   table, or when you do not specify this parameter (which is the
>   default).
>
> When the LOB value is NULL (regardless of the LOB storage properties
>   for the column).
>
> Using the default LOB storage properties (inline storage) can allow
>   for better database performance; it avoids the overhead of creating
>   and managing out-of-line storage for smaller LOB values. If LOB values
>   stored in your database are frequently small in size, then using
>   inline storage is recommended.

Comment: Sorry for not phrasing the question clearly enough: I'm only interested in the lobsegment. I assume that `STORAGE IN ROW` is just the same for `BASICFILE` and `SECUREFILE`.

Comment: if its stored out of line, I believe the minimum depends on the tablespace block size where the LOB resides